# Timestamp value in date datatype column in hive

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, hiveql, hadoop2

I have a table with with a date column(partition) and a timestamp value got inserted into it. This results when i show partitions that particular table i get to see the date value along with some numerical values wth %3A in between some numbers.

When i select that particular partitions with a select column having a where clause in that everything including the date and %3A numbers i am getting zero counts/results.

This means that i am not able to select that particular column in that table.
Is there any possible way to select that particular values.

Comment: can you post screen shot if possible ??

Comment: can you paste the `show partitions` output?

Comment: run_date=2020-06-15 17%3A40%3A38.382